# Variations of M,n,k-games

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory

I just read about [M,n,k-games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M,n,k-game) and wondered if the following variation (with fixed $k$) has been studied as well and if there exists a name for it:

Two players consecutively mark elements of ${\bf Z}$ (but could be ${\bf Z}\times{\bf Z}$ as well) in their respective color and first player who owns elements $x,x+c,\dots ,x+(k-1)\cdot c$ with $x$ arbitrary and $c\neq 0$ wins the game.

I thought that this ruleset seems more elegant from a mathematical point of view since it generalizes straightforwardly to arbitrary groups.

Also, what if the game is played on an arbitrary graph and first player who owns $k$ connected vertices wins, does this make any sense or has any name?

Comment: I think this may be called the Arithmetic Progression Game. See the book by Jozsef Beck, Combinatorial Games.

Comment: That's it, thank you so much!